# Capturing exit code from sudo-run process

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have a script in which I'm meticulously checking return codes for error conditions, so that I can abort early in the event of a failure. One step of this script involves running a command as the `root` user on another box, via `ssh` and `sudo`.

Consider:

```
ssh $HOST sudo $CMD
echo $?
```

`ssh` passes return codes back just fine, but even if `$CMD` returns a nonzero exit code, `sudo` still returns 0 after running the command.

How do I capture the return code to `$CMD`? I'm very partial to its being passed back as `ssh`'s return code, but if there's another simple method which can't be confused by the output of `$CMD`, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, `sudo` *is* passing the return code properly. My test case very likely was overwriting `$?` with a subsequent execution or conditional test. I normally use a named variable to preserve `$?` to avoid such things, but there you are.

Comment: Same here - i was echoing the result, so although ssh was passing the status code correctly, echo was returning 0.